# RecyclerView not showing items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

can someone help me, im new in android studio so i need someone to help me. i try to use recyclerview it show in my layout but when i try to run it, the items doesnt show at all. no error at all, i already add the library in build.gradle too[this is the recyclerview in my layout][1]

layout_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Messages"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvTitle" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etSearch"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:paddingHorizontal="4dp"
    android:paddingVertical="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvMessages"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etSearch"
    tools:listitem="@layout/card_layout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

card_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:padding="16dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivAvatar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="Ollie Barrie"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/ivAvatar"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tvTime"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="Hello world, I'm Kohaku from Japan. ini tulisan panjang"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tvBadges"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/ivAvatar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="20.14"
    android:textColor="@color/teal_700"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvBadges"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:text="3"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvDescription"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvDescription" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you have post your code with question not just layout ..

Answer (score 0):

tools:listitem="@layout/card_layout" this line only work in xml layout not in main code you have to add adapter in recycler view if you want to show item in recycler.

Comment: that's right. But you might also explain the difference between `tools`, `app` and `android` tags

Answer (score 0):

in the recyclerView you can't initial item to show in recyclerView in device.
you should create adapter for this, inflate your layout and pass data to this.
for more information check this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview